# Why does IntelliJ IDE keep removing $this-> from my class internal variables

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.3 with the PHP support plugin installed.

Whenever I have a class variable written as
$this->myvar I see it as myvar within IDEA, I do not like this behavior and do not see how to disable it!

```
class X {
  
public function ($inputvar)
  $iv = $this->inputvar;  // this becomes  $iv = inputvar
}
```

I checked with a different IDE and the code is not modified it is just a visibility tweak that IDE does.

How can I disable this?
It constantly keeps happening. Everytime I try to re-add $this-> and save it. Eventually, when I re-open the file its back to that new hidden format which is very annoying.

**EDIT**

with intellij (note: the $this-> disappeared for all, it only re-appeared for one as I tried to manually re-add it. However when I try to manually re-add $this from IntelliJ I then get 2 $this appear as the original hidden $this comes back as well. So I'm pretty certain its some kind of display hack from the IDE.
[image: with IntelliJ]
the tooltip for the variable says "Property accessed via magic method"

with vscode
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following what exactly is happening in IDE. Could you please describe it in another way or attach a before-after screenshot?

Comment: I just added screenshots

Comment: @user391986 1) Are you saying that `$this->` is actually there but somehow "hidden"? Or is it gets "removed" completely? Can you make a small screencast for that to clarify the behaviour? 2) Never seen anything like that (using PhpStorm though). Could be one of the plugins... Can you please disable ALL 3rd party (not bundled by default) plugins, restart IDE and see if it makes things any different.

Comment: Yes exactly it’s somehow hidden but re rappers randomly when I try to fiddle with the variable but I checked in a different IDE and it’s always there even though it disappears in IDEA. I will try thanks

Comment: as advised above, please try to disable all downloaded plugins (leave PHP plugin enabled). Next: are you working with a locally stored project or is it on a network drive?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin that removes the `$this->` is this one: [PHP Foldings](https://github.com/wbars/PHPFoldings). Check your plugins list and disable it.